# WPF change value of a child inside UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I need to change a value from **MainWindow** of a **Control** inside my **CustomControl**.
So lets say I want to change the *Labels* **Content** inside *UserControl* **MyControl** from **MainWindow.xaml**.

Example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXXXX.MyUserControl"
.
.
.
>
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="TestLabel"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And in MainWindow.xaml:
`<MyUserControl x:Name="TestControl" />`

Now how can I access Label.Content from Xaml Designer in MainWindow.xaml?

I didn't find anything out there, so hopefully someone knows how to do that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: So what does your code look like?

Comment: Have you tried having the user control use the same data context as the main window?

Comment: @Bryan how would this look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the Following to your UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="XXXXX.MyUserControl"
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
.
.
>
```

Have the User Control Implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Add a Property to the user control like this

```
   Private _LabelText As String 
    Public Property LabelText() As String
        Get
            Return _LabelText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _LabelText = value
            OnPropertyChanged("LabelText")
        End Set
    End Property
```

Update the Label to Bind from that Property

```
<Label x:Name="TestLabel" Content="{Binding Path=LabelText}"/>
```

Then in your MainWindow you can change the property accourdingly

```
<MyUserControl x:Name="TestControl" LabelText="Testing" />
```

Then your code behind can also reference that property

Comment: Well yes, this would work if I want to set a Single or a few Properties of that Label, but what if I want to set a hundred? With this method I would have to create a hundred new properties, which would be totally oversized. The better solution would be to directly Bind to the labels property from MainWindow.Xaml

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin what you are asking for would make more sense to remove the user control entirely.  But if you want to keep the user control and be able to bind to values to controls, I think this is what you want

Comment: Because of reusability it would be extremely helpful if it could be inside a UserControl and as simple as it could be. Is there no real possibility to access to Label inside that UserControl directly? This way you would have the complete access to all properties of that Label

Comment: Not that I am familiar with.  My answer is what I would do, if you wanted to keep the user control.  But if need to change that many properties then I would recommend reviewing the design of your user control

Answer (score 1):

Expose a custom Property in your UserControl, like below

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(LabelContentProperty, typeof(MyUserControl));
        dpd.AddValueChanged(this, (sender, args) =>
        {
            _label.Content = this.LabelContent;           
        });
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelContent", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));

    public string LabelContent
    {
        get 
        {
            return GetValue(LabelContentProperty) as string;
        }
        set 
        {
            SetValue(LabelContentProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

In xaml of MainWindow

```
<MyUserControl x:Name="TestControl" LabelContent="Some Content"/>
```